# How to remove all characters from a string before a specific character

Tags: c#, string, substring, trim

Suppose I have a string `A`, for example:

```
string A = "Hello_World";
```

I want to remove all characters up to (and including) the `_`. The exact number of characters before the `_` may vary. In the above example, `A == "World"` after removal.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
string A = "Hello_World";
string str = A.Substring(A.IndexOf('_') + 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

You have already received [a perfectly fine answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27183358/240733). If you are willing to go one step further, you could wrap up the `a.SubString(a.IndexOf('_') + 1)` in a robust and flexible extension method:

```
public static string TrimStartUpToAndIncluding(this string str, char ch)
{
    if (str == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("str");
    int pos = str.IndexOf(ch);
    if (pos >= 0)
    {
        return str.Substring(pos + 1);
    }
    else // the given character does not occur in the string
    {
        return str; // there is nothing to trim; alternatively, return `string.Empty`
    }
}
```

which you would use like this:

```
"Hello_World".TrimStartUpToAndIncluding('_') == "World"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string a = "Hello_World";
a = a.Substring(a.IndexOf("_")+1);
```

try this? or is the A= part in your A=Hello_World included?

Answer (score 0):

```
var foo = str.Substring(str.IndexOf('_') + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string orgStr = "Hello_World";
string newStr = orgStr.Substring(orgStr.IndexOf('_') + 1);
```

Answer (score -1):

you can do this by creating a substring.

simple exampe is here:

```js
public static String removeTillWord(String input, String word) {
    return input.substring(input.indexOf(word));
}

removeTillWord("I need this words removed taken please", "taken");
```